# Sitecore RichText field not indexing correctly in Solr in Prodcution only

Tags: solr, sitecore

I have a field whose type is set to Rich text in Sitecore.
On lower environments, the values get indexed correctly and HTML text is stored in Solr correctly.

On Production, **for all items** the HTML gets stripped off completely.

**UPDATE: One difference is that in lower environments, we have Solr on Prem and on Production, it is Solr cloud**

**UPDATE: I have checked the CM and CD servers and all have the field reader for the Body Copy field**

**UPDATE: This is now happening for all items. Earlier, possibly the other items weren't updated and published and so they showed the HTML correctly?**

What could the issue be?

1. It is only happening on **Production**
2. I have validated the config is as expected. The field is Body Copy

   ```
      <fieldReaders type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.FieldReaderMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
        <param desc="id">defaultFieldReaderMap</param>
        <mapFieldByTypeName hint="raw:AddFieldReaderByFieldTypeName">
          <fieldReader fieldTypeName="html|rich text"                                       fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.RichTextFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
        </mapFieldByTypeName>
              <mapFieldByFieldName hint="raw:AddFieldReaderByFieldName">
                  <fieldReader fieldName="Body Copy" fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.DefaultFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
              </mapFieldByFieldName>
      </fieldReaders>
   ```
3. It is now happening for all the  content

- I have resolved the HTML errors in the fields that reported HTML errors but that didn't fix it either.

Comment: Does it happen consistently for the same content items or for random ones?

Comment: Randomly to different items

Comment: Please check that you have only one server performing indexing in production. It sounds like you may have another server that doesn't have a field reader for the Body Copy field in the config. If this server has "Indexing" role and non-manual index strategies, it can pick up events from the EventQueue and index items. I saw similar issues in production environments caused by Disaster Recovery and EXM dedicated dispatch servers trying to perform indexing when they shouldn't.

Comment: One difference is that in lower environments, we have Solr on Prem and on Production, it is Solr cloud

Comment: Update: I have checked the CM and CD servers and all have the field reader for the Body Copy field

Comment: "It is only happening for some content and not for the rest". If the content that works and the content that does not work are using the same RTE, it is probably content related. Can you find and compare 2 set of content and see what is different ? Also, you may have some different config, perhaps <setting name="HtmlEditor.RemoveScripts" value="true" /> on local and false in prod. You should also take a look at the rich text field items in core database and compare from local to prod, maybe something was done on prod that was not done locally.

Comment: As per Anna's comment, can you confirm only one sitecore instance has the indexing role specified time in web config? (Including processing instance if used)

Comment: Yes, I confirmed that there is only one Sitecore instance with the indexing role

Comment: **Updated**: It is now happening for all the items. Being Production, the content authors hadn't published the entire tree. After doing this, all the items lose their HTML formatting now.

Answer (score 0):

If its happening uniformly to all fields, then my guess is that it has got to be your SOLR configuration.

Please review the managed-schema.xml document for the relevant SOLR Core on both your test and your production system.

You can do this via the file system (on prem):
i.e. C:\Solr\server\solr\web_index\conf\managed-schema.xml

Or via the SOLR dashboard (cloud and prem):
i.e. https://solr-domain:8983/solr/#/web_index/files?file=managed-schema

I suspect you will find a difference relating to filters.

Please see **HTMLStripCharFilterFactory** on this link for an example of a filter which would cause the issues you are describing:
https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_1/charfilterfactories.html#solr-htmlstripcharfilterfactory

Let me know if that helps at all.

Regards
Dean